# Choosing at random with Replacement. pmf? E(x)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

There are $30$ balls in a box. $6$ of them are red, $10$ are white and $14$ are blue. $10$ balls are chosen at random with replacement.

Let $X$ be the the number of red balls in the sample.

1) write $f(x)$, the p.m.f of X

2) $E(x)$

3) $P\{X=3\}$

4) $P\{X=7\}$

So far i get $f(x)={10 \choose X}.2^x.8^{10-x}$ for $x\in\{0,..,10\}$.

How would i compute the $E(X)$?

I think in order to get $P\{X=3\}$  I just have to plug $3$ in $f(x)$ right?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are right about $f(x)$, and needing $f(3)$, $f(7)$. For the mean, the binomial with "$n$" and "$p$" has mean $np$. Or else you could do it the long way, $0\cdot\Pr(X=0)+1\cdot\Pr(X=1)+2\cdot\Pr(X=2)+\cdots$. I expect you would rather not!

Comment: quick question how about if it's without replacement, would the mean be the same right?

Comment: Yes, you get the hypergeometric, it has mean $(10)\frac{6}{30}$. There is a cute proof using indicator random variables that also works for the binomial.